# Faith VS Great faith(Difference)?

Tags: meaning, difference

**She has  faith in modern medicine vs She has great faith in modern medicine.**

As per Cambridge dictionary faith means—great trust or confidence in st, then why there are many example sentence where "great" is being used as adjective before "faith" like in the example sentence.

Another example:—
**You'll cope - I have great faith in you.**

Comment: ***faith*** would generally be considered "gradable" - it's not really an "all-or-nothing" attribute. So it's perfectly natural to say *I have **no faith** in your approach, He has **little faith** in acupuncture, We have **total faith** in your ability to fix things.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Then it contradicts the grammar rules. (I think there are some rules about this?)

Comment: Sam: if a competent naive speaker gives examples that you think break some grammatical rule, most likely either you've been taught a worthless rule, or you haven't understood it correctly. What do you think might be wrong? *Why?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers When faith means "complete trust", then what is the reason to use it(complete) again.

Comment: One obvious reason is ***emphasis***. Did you think there might be a rule against constructions like [***complete and utter faith***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22complete+and+utter+faith%22)? That link will be for probably hundreds of written examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for your painstaking effort.

Comment: Take note that there are two different issues involved here. Saying the same thing using different words for *emphasis* is very natural in English (see [***in no way, shape, or form***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no+way+shape+or+form%22), for example). But some terms, such as ***unique*** or ***pregnant*** are considered "absolute", so strictly speaking you can't be ***slightly** pregnant* or ***totally** unique*.  But although the first of those is definitely a bit weird, the second gets used all the time.

Comment: Sam - Where did you get the definition of faith as *complete trust*? There is nothing that says it must be complete, total, utter & unthinking. It's more accurately defined as "The assent of the mind to the truth of a proposition or statement for which there is not complete evidence; belief in general." Therefore, it can have many degrees of 'confidence'.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I found it on-Oxford dictionary of English.

Comment: Link please. [It's paywalled so you can't search it, but direct links should work for anyone.]

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I don't have any link, look it up in the dictionary(book).

Comment: Sam - I really don't need to look it up. I already know the meaning, I'm a native speaker. I wanted the link to see where your confusion had come from.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. The definition is given:-Definition:—complete trust or confidence in someone or something:
Example given:-this restores one's faith in politicians

Comment: Sam - then you need to look up more than one dictionary definition. Faith is not an absolute, like [as mentioned above] pregnancy. You cannot be a bit pregnant. There are no degrees of pregnancy; you either are or you aren't. There are, however, 'degrees of faith'. This was told to you [by another native speaker] 2 hours ago… yet you're still arguing a misconception [if you'll pardon the pun].

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I am not arguing i am trying to clear my confusion because of the meaning given in dictionary.

Comment: Then use more than one dictionary… or listen to what people are telling you.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Yes, I am listening to, Now my doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the same reason that one can have a "big giant", it is possible for a modifier to take a word and make it even stronger.

This can be for emphatic reasons, or to introduce a contrast with something in which you only have a normal amount of faith.

The reason it is common is that it is a colocation. The usual word for modifying "faith" to make it even stronger is "great".

Comment: Faith— great trust or confidence & great faith— great trust or confidence in st to the extreme. (am I correct?

Comment: The "extreme" would be ***absolute / total / the utmost** faith*, not ***great** faith*.

Comment: I'd say using "great" adds general emphasis. Words tend to get degraded by use.  So although "faith" may mean "great trust and confidence", with use it becomes less strong and mean more like "I have trust, without any real evidence", so people add the intensifier to restore the meaning.  "I really have faith someone, for real this time!"